# Basic syntax on FOR UPDATE cursor

Tags: sql-server-2005, cursor

Ok, I'm certainly familiar with walking through a table using a read-only cursor, but I can't seem to find the right syntax for actually *updating* the current row (Neither the [cursor page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) nor the [UPDATE page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) in books online seems to show this simple operation):

```
DECLARE @counter int;
SET @counter = 1;
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT RowID, Value FROM myTable
        FOR UPDATE OF Value;
OPEN myCursor;
WHILE @counter < 100
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
    UPDATE myCursor SET Value = @Counter << DOESN'T WORK 
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

I also tried just `SET Value = @Counter` and using an `INTO @Value` on the FETCH, but couldn't seem to get that to work either.

This is obviously over-simplified, there are much more efficient ways to just "count" down a column. I won't bore you with the actual calculation.

Yes, I do need a cursor and not an UPDATE on the entire table (the value for each successive row will be based on a calculation that depends on the prior row already being written).

Testing this initially on SQL 2005, but I will need to port the code to SQL 2000 and 2008 as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `WHERE CURRENT OF` -

```
DECLARE complex_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT a.BusinessEntityID
    FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS a
    WHERE RateChangeDate <> 
         (SELECT MAX(RateChangeDate)
          FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS b
          WHERE a.BusinessEntityID = b.BusinessEntityID) ;
OPEN complex_cursor;
FETCH FROM complex_cursor;
UPDATE HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
SET PayFrequency = 2 
WHERE CURRENT OF complex_cursor;
CLOSE complex_cursor;
DEALLOCATE complex_cursor;
GO
```

That is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

Comment: Ok, that seemed to work. Any significant difference between that and just doing `FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @RowID` followed by `UPDATE myTable SET Value = 2 WHERE RowID = @RowID`?

Comment: I am glad to say that I use cursors little enough not to know! :) I guess it's a case of test with a couple of rows and see how the plan looks. I can't really imagine it being much different, to be honest - especially if @RowID is the clustered index key.

Comment: Some updates to the underlying table in the cursor won't be seen unless you use the "Where Current Of" syntax - see the [Declare Cursor Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in MSDN.  Search the page for "Where current of" and you'll see the details.  It's not a common issue.