# FOR UPDATE cursor is returning a result set for each row!

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor

I'm using an UPDATE cursor as follows on SQL 2005:

```
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT RowID, Value FROM myTable
        FOR UPDATE OF Value;
OPEN myCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
    UPDATE myTable SET Value = 42
    WHERE CURRENT OF myCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

(Thanks to Matt for his correct answer on [my prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504818/basic-syntax-on-for-update-cursor) concerning this cursor syntax.  And yes, I do need a cursor, because each row's new value is actually based on a complicated calculation that depends on the prior rows.)

This works correctly, updating all the Values. The problem is that it returns a result set for each row updated, consisting of RowID, Value (interestingly, its showing the result from *before* the row is updated). Eventually, I get the following error:

> The query has exceeded the maximum
>   number of result sets that can be
>   displayed in the results grid. Only
>   the first 100 result sets are
>   displayed in the grid.

Any way to suppress these result sets? `SET NOCOUNT ON` doesn't do the trick.
Is this just an issue I see running it directly in SSMS? Or will it actually try to return hundreds of result sets when I put this cursor inside a stored proc?

**EDIT: Looks like it has nothing to do with the UPDATE.**

Using `FETCH NEXT FROM myCURSOR` the way I am actually does return a result set of the next row from the cursor.

If I change it to `FETCH NEXT FROM myCURSOR INTO @variables`, then it doesn't return a result set.

So I guess the question now is: Since I'm using `WHERE CURRENT OF`, I don't really *need* the variable. I guess I can put them in just to suppress the result set, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Coudl you maybe **at least** make it a `FAST_FORWARD` cursor to lessen the impact a cursor has??

Comment: `FAST_FORWARD` cursors are read-only. Not compatible with `FOR UPDATE`

Comment: @BradC, you say: "_And yes, I do need a cursor, because each row's new value is actually based on a complicated calculation that depends on the prior rows._" .... Since you were on SQL2k5, you had ranking functions which would almost certainly have been a better solution than the cursor. Even still, older versions of SQL Server had some useful tricks to avoid cursors. If you had posted your **real** problem, rather than the artificial one you inflicted on yourself, you might have got a much better answer.

Comment: @BradC PS: Given your error: "_maximum number of result sets that can be displayed in the results grid_" ... surely the simplest solution was to set your query options to send **Results to Text** instead of **Results to Grid**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note while begin ... end
and Fetch into

```
Declare @row int
Declare @value int
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT RowID, Value FROM myTable
        FOR UPDATE OF Value;
OPEN myCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor into @row, @value
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 1)
begin   
    UPDATE myTable SET Value = 42
    WHERE CURRENT OF myCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor into @row, @value
END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Comment: Guess that works. If I'm going to have the variable anyway, I might as well just change it to a `FAST_FORWARD` cursor and do `UPDATE myTable SET Value = 42 WHERE RowID = @row`. I guess then I don't really see the point of using a `FOR UPDATE` cursor.

Comment: Yes that's the way I do it too. Never used for update in production code